# Application could not be uploaded to the device

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

**Following are the details about Xamarin, studio and Mac:**
Visual Studio Community 2019 for Mac
Version 8.6.8 (build 2)
Xamarin.Mac 6.18.0.23
.NET Core SDK
SDK: /usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/3.1.302/Sdks
SDK Version: 3.1.302
MSBuild SDKs: /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/6.10.0/lib/mono/msbuild/Current/bin/Sdks

.NET Core Runtime
Runtime: /usr/local/share/dotnet/dotnet
Runtime Versions:
3.1.6
2.1.20

Xamarin.Profiler
Version: 1.6.15.68
Location: /Applications/Xamarin Profiler.app/Contents/MacOS/Xamarin Profiler

Updater
Version: 11
Apple Developer Tools
Xcode 12.0 (17189.4)
Build 12A8169g

Xamarin.iOS
Version: 13.18.2.1 (Visual Studio Community)
Operating System
Mac OS X 10.15.6
Darwin 19.6.0 Darwin Kernel Version 19.6.0

**Issue:**
/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/Current/bin/mlaunch -sdkroot "/Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer" --installdev "/Users/*******/Projects/testApp/testApp/bin/iPhone/Debug/device-builds/iphone11.6-13.5.1/testApp.app" --device ios "--devname=iPhone XS Max" --install-progress
error HE0004: Could not load the framework 'IDEKit' (path: /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Frameworks/IDEKit.framework/IDEKit): dlopen(/Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Frameworks/IDEKit.framework/IDEKit, 1): Library not loaded: @rpath/DVTAnalyticsKit.framework/Versions/A/DVTAnalyticsKit
Referenced from: /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Frameworks/IDEKit.framework/Versions/A/IDEKit
Reason: image not found

All the paths are correct and file exist there.

This is just a sample project and its failing to deploy on physical device. I am able to deploy via XCode but it fails via Mac Visual Studio. Need some help here. I am going to install different version of XCode and try it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Xcode 12 beta you need a newer version of Xamarin.iOS from the [xcode12](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/commits/xcode12) branch. Quoting from the [wiki](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/wiki#downloading-a-build) on how to get a build from the said branch:

> If you go to our [commits](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/commits/xcode12) page you should be able to see a green checkmark (✔) or a red cross mark (✘) at the right side of the committer's handle. If you click the checkmark (it's usually best to use builds with green checkmarks, but in some cases there may be none, in which case you can likely use builds with red checkmarks as well) you should see a details link which will provide download links for both Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.Mac packages for that specific commit. Once in a while a commit may not have associated builds (this can occur both for red and green builds) - just try a different commit.

Make sure you download the "Notarized" version of the pkgs.

Answer (score 0):

Uninstalled Xcode 12 beta and installed Xcode 11.6 (Hosted in VM).
It worked successfully.
Now i am able to deploy from Visual Studio 2019 running on windows.